# Cause browser to highlight text on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason all the text in draggable elements in a site I'm building are no longer highlightable.

I want them to be highlightable.

Is there a way I can cause the browser's highlight on click in js / jQuery.

I know one can wrap the text highlighted in a span and then style it, but its there a way to cause the browser's highlight?

If that is not possible how can I go about making something that functions like the highlight? Is it possible to trigger the contextual menu of a browser in js / jQuery ?

I have tried [this plugin](https://github.com/kasperp/highlight), which wraps spans around the the text, unfortunately it does work on click and drag like normal highlighting, well I haven't figured out how to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "highlight"?   Do you mean what happens when the user selects text on the page?

I suspect that what's going on is that you're using jQuery Draggable, which disables text selection (because it interferes with the drag action.)

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, exactly.

Comment: OK, best solution for this is probably to use Draggable's "handle" option rather than making the entire element draggable.

Comment: @DanielBeck But that makes it draggable by another object.

Comment: Yep.   If the whole element is draggable, then selectable text doesn't work (because the browser can't know whether the user intended to drag the element or select the text), so Draggable disables text selection on draggable elements.  If you need to allow text selection, you need to use a drag handle that is inside the draggable item but separate from the selectable text.

Comment: wont let it be selectable either using handle @DanielBeck Unless you have it as input type=text or something like that. http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, it is still not selectable, even with handle.

Comment: Aw, jeez, you're right. I apologize, I could swear that used to work...